# build.gradle: compile group vs compile, buildscript, classpath

Tags: java, gradle

What is the difference between "compile group" and "compile"? Just another way to define a dependency?

Ex:

```
compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-jcl', version: '1.7.21'
```

And i think this also will work:

```
compile("org.slf4j:slf4j-jcl:1.7.21")
```

Why do i have the declare `mavenCentral()` again and another dependencies block inside the buildscript block?

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.4.0.RELEASE")
    }
}
```

From my point of view, when you compile something it will be in your classPath?

Comment: The two versions of `compile` are synonymous and behave exactly the same. The `dependencies` block shouldn't *need* to be in the `buildscript` block.

Comment: in the `buildscript` block you're specifying the dependencies for the gradle build script it self (They're used when compiling the build.gradle file). It's useful for when you want a library for build but the application does not need it. For example, you may want to use a ssh library for build but your application does not need it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`compile` specifies an external dependency for the project you are building. `compile` requires group, name, and version. These can either be broken out or specified using the short form *"group:name:version"*. see [Gradle Dependency Management Basics](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html)

The `buildscript` block declares the dependencies of your gradle build itself while the *normal* dependencies block declares the dependencies of the project you are going to build